# how to run the code before the app.run() in flask?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm new on flask.I configured a server with flask+gunicorn.

the code file called `test.py` like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def test():
    return aa+"world!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    aa = "hello"
    app.run()
```

run it using：`gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8080 test:app`

I got a mistake：`NameError: name 'aa' is not defined.`

I want some codes like variable `aa` runing before gunicorn.

How to do that？

Comment: What is `a` ? That `a` is indeed undefined..

Comment: sorry,it is 'aa'.I edited it

Comment: And the a+"world" should also be `aa`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put in a small block just before your `@app.route` and you dont need the last block in the question

```
 @app.before_first_request
 def _declareStuff():
     global aa
     aa='hello'
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Flask 2.2, the `@app.before_first_request` decorator [suggested by Vipluv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50249774/20839213) in their answer is deprecated and [will be removed](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request) in 2.3.

> Deprecated since version 2.2: Will be removed in Flask 2.3. Run setup code when creating the application instead.

The equivalent can be done by [manually pushing the app context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/appcontext/#manually-push-a-context), [as suggested by Enkum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73570041/flask-deprecated-before-first-request-how-to-update/74629704#74629704) :

```py
# In place of something like this
@app.before_first_request
def create_tables():
    db.create_all()
    ...

# USE THIS INSTEAD
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

Comment: This has the caveat of being run every time your app starts, even when not running the server. This may not be desirable if you make heavy use of `app.cli`.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare `aa` outside of "`__main__`", in the global scope of the file.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def test():
    return aa+"world!"

aa = "hello"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The code in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block executes only if the Python code is run as a script, e.g., from the command line. Gunicorn imports the file, so in that case the code in `__main__` will not be executed.

---

Note that if it is your intention to modify the value of `aa` then different requests can produce different results depending on how many requests each gunicorn worker process has handled. e.g.:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def test():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    return "{} world! {}".format('aa', counter)

counter = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Run the above script with more than one worker (`gunicorn -w 2 ...`) and make several requests to the URL. You should see that the counter is not always contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

1. The script creates a Flask web application.
2. It defines a function (declareStuff) to be executed before each incoming request. Inside this function, it sets a value ('hello') to the attribute 'aa' of Flask's special g object.
3. The script defines a route for the root URL ('/') and a corresponding
   function (test). When a user accesses this URL, the function returns a response that includes the value stored in g.aa.
4. The application is configured to run on host '0.0.0.0' and port '8080' with debugging enabled.

In summary, the script initializes a Flask app, uses the g object to store data to each request, and responds to the root URL with the stored value followed by ' world!'. This demonstrates the use of Flask's before_request hook and the g object for managing data during the processing of HTTP requests.

```
from flask import Flask, g

app = Flask(__name__)

# This function is executed before each request
@app.before_request
def declareStuff():
    # Set a value 'hello' to the attribute 'aa' of the 'g' object
    g.aa = 'hello'

# Define a route and corresponding function for the root URL
@app.route('/')
def test():
    # Return a response composed of the value stored in g.aa followed by ' world!'
    return f"{g.aa} world!"

# Run the Flask application
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Run the application on host 0.0.0.0, port 8080, with debugging enabled
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, debug=True)
```